# Get Current date in SQLBase

Tags: sql, sqlbase

I have an SQLBase and I am trying to get the current date of the system to be equal to the date of a column (create_date).

The MySQL Code will be:

```
Select * From Date D
Where D.Create_date=CURDATE();
```

Can someone suggest me a way to take the current date in a SQLBase?

The date format should only contain the date(yyyy-MM-dd) and not the timestamp.

Comment: I know this has already been answered , but if you need to know more about SQLBase, here is a link to some manuals for every version from v8 thru v12.1  :  http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current date, and not time, you should be able to use `@DATEVALUE(@NOW)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should I use the command like: where d.create_date=@DATEVALUE(@NOW)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I will try it later this week.If it works I will accept it! Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

This should get you the results you want:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
Col1 NVARCHAR(1)
,Date  date 
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES 
('a','2017-12-08')
,('b','2017-12-08')


SELECT *
FROM @Temp
WHERE Date = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Comment: getdate() isn't a valid function in SQLBase

Comment: This looks more like SQLServer - its def not SQLBase. No CONVERT, no DECLARE, no getdate()